# need help with this Kombu error

Tags: python, kombu

Pardon the copy and paste from the python interpreter but I'm trying to play with Kombu but I can't seem to create a consumer. Please help, I'm utterly in the dark here.

```
>>> from kombu.messaging import Consumer, Producer
>>> from kombu.entity import Exchange, Queue
>>> x = Exchange("stmt",type="topic")
>>> helloQ = Queue("hello", exchange=x, routing_key="stmt.hello")
>>>
>>> from kombu.connection import BrokerConnection
>>> conn = BrokerConnection("scheduledb.lab.compete.com", "clippy", "clippy", "clippy")
>>> channel = conn.channel()
>>> c = Consumer(channel, helloQ)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kombu-1.0.6-py2.6.egg/kombu/messaging.py", line 231, in __init__
self.declare()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kombu-1.0.6-py2.6.egg/kombu/messaging.py", line 241, in declare
    queue.declare()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kombu-1.0.6-py2.6.egg/kombu/entity.py", line 362, in declare
    self.name and self.queue_declare(nowait, passive=False),
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kombu-1.0.6-py2.6.egg/kombu/entity.py", line 380, in queue_declare
    nowait=nowait)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kombu-1.0.6-py2.6.egg/kombu/syn.py", line 14, in blocking
    return __sync_current(fun, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kombu-1.0.6-py2.6.egg/kombu/syn.py", line 30, in __blocking__
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
File "build/bdist.cygwin-1.7.8-i686/egg/amqplib/client_0_8/channel.py", line 1294, in queue_declare
File "build/bdist.cygwin-1.7.8-i686/egg/amqplib/client_0_8/abstract_channel.py", line 89, in wait
File "build/bdist.cygwin-1.7.8-i686/egg/amqplib/client_0_8/connection.py", line 218, in _wait_method
File "build/bdist.cygwin-1.7.8-i686/egg/amqplib/client_0_8/abstract_channel.py", line 105, in wait
File "build/bdist.cygwin-1.7.8-i686/egg/amqplib/client_0_8/connection.py", line 367, in _close
amqplib.client_0_8.exceptions.AMQPConnectionException: (530, u"NOT_ALLOWED - parameters for queue 'hello' in vhost 'clippy' not equivalent", (50, 10), 'Channel.queue_declare')
>>> boundX = x(helloQ)
>>> c = Consumer(channel, helloQ)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kombu-1.0.6-py2.6.egg/kombu/messaging.py", line 231, in __init__
    self.declare()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kombu-1.0.6-py2.6.egg/kombu/messaging.py", line 241, in declare
    queue.declare()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kombu-1.0.6-py2.6.egg/kombu/entity.py", line 361, in declare
    return (self.name and self.exchange.declare(nowait),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kombu-1.0.6-py2.6.egg/kombu/entity.py", line 151, in declare
nowait=nowait)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kombu-1.0.6-py2.6.egg/kombu/syn.py", line 14, in blocking
    return __sync_current(fun, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kombu-1.0.6-py2.6.egg/kombu/syn.py", line 30, in __blocking__
     return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "build/bdist.cygwin-1.7.8-i686/egg/amqplib/client_0_8/channel.py", line 839, in exchange_declare
  File "build/bdist.cygwin-1.7.8-i686/egg/amqplib/client_0_8/abstract_channel.py", line 69, in _send_method
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'method_writer'
```

Comment: I would highly suggest not using Cygwin, and using RabbitMQ if you aren't just doing this as an experiment.

Comment: Can you explain what Cygwin has to do with it. I am running python through cygwin, not much else....

Comment: Cygwin is not supported. I checked on the #python channel on Freenode. Not 100% sure though.;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to @asksol's answer.  If you are using rabbitmq you can use the [rabbitmqctl](http://www.rabbitmq.com/man/rabbitmqctl.1.man.html#Commands) command to list the queue details and compare those settings with the settings in your own code.  Hopefully that gives you enough information to detect the conflict.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the error

```
amqplib.client_0_8.exceptions.AMQPConnectionException: (530, u"NOT_ALLOWED - parameters for queue 'hello' in vhost 'clippy' not equivalent", (50, 10), 'Channel.queue_declare')
```

This means the queue has already been declared, but with other parameters than what you
are declaring it with now.

Comment: yes, i see that. but WHAT parameters? Where were these set? How can I find the parameters that were set? What is it expecting and what did it get?